# La phrase nominale « je ne sais quoi » et la phrase adjectif « je ne sais quel/quelle »

Tags: expressions

> Je prie pour que tu trouves la paix, à passer ta vie à chercher **je ne sais quoi**, mais ne me recontacte plus.

Est-ce que cette expression veut dire que, quels que soient le but et le rêve que son interlocuteur tient à poursuivre, la locutrice s'en fiche éperdument ?

> Il a fallu qu'il aille encore se fourrer dans **je ne sais quel** pétrin !

Celle-ci signifie-t-elle, en revanche, que la locutrice ne sait pas au juste dans quel genre de pétrin s'est retrouvé son interlocuteur ? Et cela la contrarie plutôt qu'elle ne s'en moque ?

Comment: C'est très simple: la première expression est un substantif and la deuxième tient lieu d'adjectif. Elles ont le même sens. QED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne sais XXX = fait référence à quelque chose que je ne connais pas où que je ne comprends pas - avec un sous-entendu de n'importe quoi (ou qui m'indiffère).

**Les deux interprétations (n'importe quoi / qui m'indiffère ou pas) sont possibles en fonction du contexte.**

- La première phrase indique clairement : je m'en moque.
- La seconde indique qu'on ne sait pas *dans quel pétrin* il a été se fourrer, mais sans savoir précisément si on s'en moque ou pas .

Je ne sais quoi = n'importe quoi

Je ne sais qui = n'importe qui

Je ne sais quel XXX = n'importe quel XXX

Je ne sais comment = n'importe comment

Je ne sais où = n'importe où

Je ne sais pourquoi = pour n'importe quelle raison